# Cursor jumping backwards

Tags: windows, keyboard

When I type text on my laptop, sometimes the cursor jumps backwards. Here's an example of a sentence which I have just typed into the question box:

1We 2hold 3theo 6be 7self-evident, 8that 9all 10men 11are 12created 13equal...se 4truths 5t

After the "t" in "5to", the cursor jumps back to the first "e" in "these". It's not an application-specific problem; the same thing happens when I use Notepad and Notepad++. Curiously, "t" seems to the most error-prone key. Have you ever experienced something similar?

Techincal specs:
* Lenovo G560 laptop
* Windows 7 Ultimate operating system (64-bit).

Things I have tried which didn't help:
* Re-installing Windows 7
* Running a full virus scan with Microsoft Security Essentials

Comment: Have you tried this on a different Lenovo G560 laptop with same exact settings? If both give the same result then it is worthed to find out what app might be causing it, otherwise it is onlt on that specific Lenovo G560 laptop that problem happens then change the laptop.

Comment: Sound like an error in the the keyboard controller(hardware). sound like its sending carriage return or left arrow when you press T. the best way to fix this is to replace the keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try turning tapping off on your touch Pad, you could be accidentally selecting earlier parts of your text, in most drivers you can disable tapping for x seconds while typing.

Answer (score 0):

Lenovo G780 with same issue. When typing, try positioning the arrow below and to the side of the text in the input dialog box. If the arrow  is horizontal with any line and you brush the touchpad the cursor will jump to that line. Likewise, if the arrow is positioned below a line of text and you brush the touchpad the cursor will jump to the character directly above the arrow's position. Experiment. You will see what I mean. Annoying to be sure, but move the arrow out of the  line of fire.